# Jmeter for cloud apps

Tags: jmeter

We are trying to do performance testing for cloud apps which has single sign on option. We are unable to navigate to home screen as the load runner is unable to identify the token. Has anyone recorded cloud app which has single sign on authentication?

Thanks in advance

We have tried to record and capture dynamic values in jmeter but failed to do so

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types of single sign on implementations like:

1. [NTLM SSO](https://siddhivinayak-sk.medium.com/ntlm-based-user-authentication-and-sso-in-web-application-4450eadb2332)
2. [Kerberos SSO](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/engineering-lifecycle-management-suite/lifecycle-management/7.0.0?topic=management-configuring-kerberosspnego-sso)
3. [SAML SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)
4. Custom implementation

In cases 1 and 2 you will need to add properly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) article for more details.

For other SSO options it should be a matter of implementing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start). The easiest way of identifying dynamic values is recording the same scenario twice and comparing resulting .jmx scripts. All the values which differ are a subject to correlation.